# How to find element based on string that may span multiple child tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to identify specific elements within a document based on a known text string. Normally, you could easily do this with

```
soup.find(string=re.compile(".*some text string.*"))
```

However the known string may have (multiple) child elements within it. For example, if this is our document:

```py
test_doc = BeautifulSoup("""<html><h1>Title</h1><p>Some <b>text</b></p>""")
```

and I'm looking for a specific element. The only thing I know about this element is that it contains the text "Some text". I *don't* know that the word "text" within it is in a child bold tag.

```py
test_doc.find(string=re.compile(".*Some text.*"))
```

is `None` because "text" is within that child tag.

How can I return the parent tag (the `p` tag in my example), with all the children tags, if I don't know if/how the text is broken up into child tags?

Comment: The child tags are only `<b>`?

Comment: Is `lxml` and alternative? There's an approach using xpath.

Comment: @LMC I would be interested in the XPATH approach with `lxml`

Comment: @HedgeHog added that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Lots of great ideas here, will be reviewing them, and hopefully doing some speed tests if I have time, over the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought, against the background that it is not clear which or how many tags can be nested, here was `css selector` with pseudo class `:-soup-contains("some text")`, but this probably overshoots the mark, as it returns also all overlying combinations that contain the text.

Certainly not the nicest or even most resilient approach, but perhaps a solution can be found from there, is to pick out the smallest element combination that holds your text in each case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

test_doc = BeautifulSoup("""<html><h1>Title</h1><p>Some <b>text</b></p><div><p>Some <i>text</i> different than <div>before</div></p></div>""", 'html.parser')

selection = test_doc.select(':-soup-contains("Some text")')

for i,el in enumerate(selection):
    if len(selection[i].find_all()) <len(selection[i-1].find_all()):
           del selection[i-1]

print(selection)
```

What results in:

```
[<p>Some <b>text</b></p>, <p>Some <i>text</i> different than <div>before</div></p>]
```

---

An alternative, if a certain set of tags could be identified that thwarts your actual approach, would be to [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) them first - Think that is a reason also @Andrej Kesely asks for some specific tags.

Comment: Yes, `unwrap()` was my first thought. But you answer inspired me to make something similar. Using `in` operator (you can check `tag1 in tag2` to remove the overlapping tags).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, inspired by @HedgeHog's answer:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_doc = BeautifulSoup(
    """<html><h1>Title</h1><p>Some <b>text</b></p><div><p>Some <i>text</i> different than <div>before</div></p></div>""",
    "html.parser",
)


tags = test_doc.find_all(lambda tag: "Some text" in tag.text)
out = []
while tags and (t := tags.pop()):
    while tags and t in tags[-1]:
        tags.pop()
    out.append(t)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[<p>Some <i>text</i> different than <div>before</div></p>, <p>Some <b>text</b></p>]
```

Comment: Brilliant - I'm always thrilled when alternative solutions pop up.  This one is cool and even seems cleaner to me, because the 'in' operator for the comparison seems more suitable than the length comparison. Would also be worth testing on a large data set.

Comment: I did not realize you could just put a `lamda` expression into `find_all`! I had something that was doing something similar, but was manually navigating through the tree. This is much cleaner and might be faster too, I'll have to check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach using `lxml` and `xpath` that also covers the case where the expected text is contained by a single node.

```
from lxml import etree
xml = """<html><h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="target">
        <div>Some <div><div><span><b>text</b></span></div></div></div>
        <div>Some <b>another text</b></div>
        <p>Some <i>text</i> different than <div>before</div></p>
        <em>Some text</em>
    </div>
</html>"""
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

ele = root.xpath('//div[@id="target"]//*[(./text()="Some " and .//*[1]/text()="text") or ./text()="Some text"]')
print(ele)
```

`.//*[1]/text()="text"]` looks for the first descendant of the context node containing the expected string. It's case sensitive so `./text()="some "` won't find anything.

Result for the given sample

```
[<Element div at 0x7f2d65eef6c0>, <Element p at 0x7f2d65eef700>, <Element em at 0x7f2d65eef740>]
```

Extracting content from found elements

```
print([[t for t in e.xpath('descendant-or-self::text()')] for e in ele])
```

Result

```
[['Some ', 'text'], ['Some ', 'text', ' different than ', 'before'], ['Some text']]
```

Comment: Not sure if this really meets the requirements: since I don't know in advance which sections of text will be in child tags, I'd have to generate every possible split, right?

Comment: My example there is *very* simplified: my actual data often has like 5 child tags per word, so I'd literally have to generate every single possible decent tree - some *letters* might be 5 generations deep while others are just 2.

Comment: trying any descendant not just the first child `and .//*[1]/text()="text"`. I would help if you add an actual example.

Comment: Just changed the first case and fixed the xpath to find it.

Comment: The issue, which I think I was pretty clear about in the original question, is that I don't know which sections of text are in child tags in advance. You have defined `"Some "` and `"text"` explicitly. I don't know if it's going to be `<p>Some <b>text</b></p>` or `<p>So<b>me </b>t<b>ex</b>t</p>`, or any other combination of child tags.